# MacOS + Ansible upgrade from 2.1 to 2.3 - NameError: global name 'get_module' is not defined

Tags: ansible

Need a bit of help and maybe its just that i have to downgrade my ansible install. An ansible-playbook that was running in 2.1 now errors out with " NameError: global name 'get_module' is not defined". The upgrade has modules I would like to use for networking.

```
PLAY [ios] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [OBTAIN LOGIN CREDS] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.26.26.10]

TASK [DEFINE PROVIDER] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.26.26.10]

TASK [LOAD NEW ACL INTO DEVICE] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NameError: global name 'get_module' is not defined
fatal: [172.26.26.10]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/yw/l2nj7vf50dqg2hrjw8qnp9b9vkc_p4/T/ansible_4xFueF/ansible_module_ios_config.py\", line 224, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/var/folders/yw/l2nj7vf50dqg2hrjw8qnp9b9vkc_p4/T/ansible_4xFueF/ansible_module_ios_config.py\", line 177, in main\n    module = get_module(argument_spec=argument_spec,\nNameError: global name 'get_module' is not defined\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/prahbor/Documents/Scripts/ansible/parents_playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.26.26.10               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

PLAYBOOK IS

```
---
- hosts: ios
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: OBTAIN LOGIN CREDS
    include_vars: ~/Documents/Scripts/ansible/group_vars/all.yml

  - name: DEFINE PROVIDER
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
        username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        password: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"

  - name: LOAD NEW ACL INTO DEVICE
    ios_config:
      provider: "{{ provider }}"
      parents: ip access-list extended ansible_test
      lines:
        - permit tcp host 10.1.1.1 any log
        - permit tcp host 10.1.1.2 any log
        - permit tcp host 10.1.1.3 any log
        - permit tcp host 10.1.1.4 any log
        - permit tcp host 1.1.1.1 any log
        - permit tcp host 2.2.2.2 any log
      before: no ip access-list extended ansible_test
      match: exact
      replace: line
    notify: save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some other suggestions i did the following.

You will want to install from a source, not from pip.

`cd ~/`

`git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive`

`cd ./ansible`

`source ./hacking/env-setup`

All the web information found, led me to the Ansible docs over and over...
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html#running-from-source

`$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.2.0
  config file = /Users/prahbor/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides`

```
$ ansible-playbook parents_playbook --ask-vault-pass
Vault password:

PLAY [ios] *******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [OBTAIN LOGIN CREDS] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.26.26.10]

TASK [DEFINE PROVIDER] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.26.26.10]

TASK [LOAD NEW ACL INTO DEVICE] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.26.26.10]

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************
172.26.26.10               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```